# Player & Level class structure in 2D python console game?

Tags: python, data-structure, text-based

I'm trying to create a 2D console game, where I have a player who can freely move around in a level (~map, but `map` is a reserved keyword) and interfere with other objects.
`Level`s construct out of multiple `Block`s, such as player(s), rocks, etc.

Here's the `Block` class:

```
class Block(object):
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, char=' ', solid=False):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.char = char
        self.solid = solid
```

As you see, each block has a position (`x, y`) and a character to represent the block when it's printed. Each block also has a `solid` attribute, defining whether it can overlap with other `solid`s or not. (Two solid blocks cannot overlap)

I've now created few subclasses from `Block` (`Rock` might be useless for now)

```
class Rock(Block):
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        super(Rock, self).__init__(x, y, 'x', True)

class Player(Block):
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        super(Player, self).__init__(x, y, 'i', True)

    def move_left(self, x=1):
        ... # How do I make sure Player wont overlap with rocks?
        self.x -= x
```

And here's the Level class:

```
class Level(object):
    def __init__(self, name='', blocks=None):
        self.name = name
        self.blocks = blocks or []
```

Only way I can think of is to store a `Player` instance into `Level`'s attributes (`self.player=Player()`, or so) and then give `Level` a method:

```
def player_move_left(self):
    for block in self.blocks:
        if block.x == self.player.x - 1 and block.solid:
            return False
```

But this doesn't really make any sense, why have a `Player` class if it can't even be moved without `Level`? Imo. player should be moved by a method inside `Player`.

Am I wrong at something here, if not, how could I implement such behavior?

Comment: Don't think of classes as "Objects", think of them as "Bundled Functionality."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different options:

**Option 1: Not making a Player class**

You keep a level attribute: `self.player = Block()`.
Then you don't have to worry for having an extra class. But in the future you might want to add extra methods/attributes to player, so perhaps it isn't the best option.

**Option 2: Player receives blocks**

```
def player_move_left(self):
    self.player.move_left(self.blocks)

# Then implement the movement in the player class
```

**Option 3: Player receives the whole level**

Player doesn't need to be an attribute of your level if you keep player as a global, ie:

```
player.move_left(level)

class Player(Block):
    ...

    def move_left(self, level):
        for block in level.blocks:
            if block.x == self.player.x - 1 and block.solid:
                return False
```

Even better, level could have a `can_move` method:

```
    def move_left(self, level):
        if level.can_move(self.player.x - 1):
            self.player.x -= 1
            return true
        else:
            return false
```